# How to speed up the request to the server? (PUGREST.Timeout)

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, session-timeout, pubchem

I run into a problem related to the server request time. In some cases (for example C2H4), it gives the result after 5-10 seconds (too slow, tho), in other cases (for example C9H8O4) it fails with timeout error. Obviosly, tha dates of both structures weight about the same. What am i doing wrong?

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
async function downloadASJson(url, fileName) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const jsonContent = await response.buffer();

  fs.writeFile(`listK.json`, jsonContent, "utf8", function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("An error occured while writing JSON Object to File.");
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("JSON file has been saved.");

  });
}

try {
  downloadASJson(
    "https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/formula/C9H8O4/JSON/?record_type=3d",
    "C9H8O4"
  );

} catch (err) {
  console.log(error);
}


var data = fs.readFileSync('/home/evvio/Desktop/ппп/listK.json', 'utf8');
var str;
str = data.slice(33, 54);
str = str.replace(',', '')
str = str.replace('"', '')
str = str.replace(/ /g, '')

if (str.length != 0){
  try {
    downloadASJson(
      "https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/listkey/" + str + "/JSON/",
      "C9H8O4"
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: That server use internal queue for serving requests. 
So issue not in you code. Probably internal database engine on that service overload by requests. If it possible choose another time for request, but often it doesn't help too((

Comment: @ivict, sad to hear :( Yeah, the result didnt change depending on the request time :(( But thanks!